# React letter game

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-functional-component

**Hit and miss game developed in react.js with functional components****

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-proskuriakova-1o0hf)

Comment: It is not allowed even to change the order of the elements in the `initialState`?

Comment: @Medi Think of a jumbled word game, but there is only one right sequence or right phrase, as in example A, B, C, D, E, F that would be the right phrase. If the return is A, B, D, C, E, F the word order is wrong and it would not be right. In this case, do you find it interesting to leave the initial state confused? Or can I choose where to place the words through the Array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve that by adding another prop to `buttons`, after being clicked without having to change the `initialState`:
I have posted only modified code, and the full example is on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-mountain-voywj?file=/src/App.js).

```
 const buttonClickHandler = (id) => {
    if (count === 0) {
      return;
    }
    setCount(count - 1);
    // Update an array of objects
     setButtons(
      initialState.map((element) =>
        [...buttons]
          .sort((a, b) => (b.label < a.label ? 1 : -1))
          .map((item, index) =>
            item.id === id
              ? {
                  ...item,
                  clicked: true,
                  inOrder: !index
                    ? item.isRight
                    : item.isRight &&
                      buttons.sort((a, b) => (b.label < a.label ? 1 : -1))[
                        index - 1
                      ].clicked,
                  disabled: true
                }
              : item
          )
          .find((item) => item.id === element.id)
      )
    );
  };
...
const checkIfCorrect = () => {
    let correct = buttons.filter(
      (item) => item.clicked === true && item.isRight === true && item.inOrder
    ).length;
    if (correct === 6) {
      setCorrect(true);
    } else {
      setCorrect(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: This case you were able to change the initial state of the buttons by checking your code here, it brings a great option too.

Comment: I could create a seperate state, but since the restriction was only not to modify the `initialState`, I thought it could be possible to change `buttons` state.

Comment: I don't know why I can't leave the correct sequence of answers without having to change the position (id) of the question buttons.

Comment: @André i forgot to restore the buttons to the original order. i updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the order of buttons in which they were clicked and the order of correct answers.

create a state for maintaining sequence of ids of the buttons in order in which they were clicked:

```
const [sequence, setSequence] = useState([]);
```

create an array with ids of buttons in correct (expected) sequence:

```
const correctSequence = [1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 4];
```

then inside `buttonClickHandler` add this code:

```
setSequence([...sequence, id]);
```

also add this code in `resetGame` function:

```
setSequence([]);
```

and finally change `checkIfCorrect` function to:

```
  const checkIfCorrect = () => {
    if (correctSequence.length === sequence.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
        if (sequence[i] !== correctSequence[i]) {
          setCorrect(false);
          return;
        }
      }
      setCorrect(true);
    } else {
      setCorrect(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: The logic of the correctness is correct, however when I click on the buttons for questions it keeps changing the order of the answers.